# What is the difference between "take in hand" and "take by the hand"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, difference, phrase-usage, phrases

Is there a difference between "take in hand" and "take by the hand"? I tried to google the meanings but it's still a little vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> take in hand

means

> bring under control

It derives, I believe, from the days of riding horses, which are controlled by reins that lead from the rider’s hands or hand to a metal bit in the horse’s mouth. Certainly when I was a small boy being taught to ride, the riding master was always telling me to “get that pony in hand.”

However, it applies figuratively to many situations.

> Once made CEO, he took that company in hand and returned it to prifitability.

Whereas

> take by the hand

means

> to grasp the hand of someone, almost always in a spirit of care or affection.

> Ruth took her granddaughter by the hand to cross the street

> The boy shyly looked at her and took her by the hand.

It is a phrase not often used figuratively although often used symbolically.

The phrases are quite different in flavor as well as meaning.

Got it now?